# Cocoa Accessibility : Parent does not report element as one of its children

Tags: cocoa, accessibility-api

I'm [developing a UI app](https://github.com/kyro38/EasyDrive) for the Mac OS. I was just using the `Accessibility Inspector` that comes with OSX when I saw this following error :

"Parent does not report element as one of its children"

[image]

Which I can understand because my cursor was over a element of a `NSCollectionView`.

So how can I "register" the subitems as children of the Collection ?

Edit: I also observe some weird behaviour: When `Accessibility Inspector` is open, every time I enter one of my subelements with my cursor I get the following message.

```
-[DriveViewBox item]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x########
```

Where `DriveViewBox` is a `NSBox` subclass.

Comment: Assuming your NSCollectView is working as expected I think you’ve found a bug. NSCollectionViews are NOT used very much inside of Apple so they don’t get a ton of love. I’d advise filing a a RADAR—http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: I must have done something wrong, https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/IconCollection/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004477 doesn't show any errors.